# Не хватает перевода на странице тревог

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, тревоги

Не хватает перевода на странице тревог. Появился новый информационный баннер:

> [image: тревоги участника]

Comment: Он не слетел. Его просто раньше не было еще. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323056/339911

Comment: @älёxölüt это добавляется какой-то новый функционал на сайте? Или просто предупреждающий баннер?

Comment: @L.F.C. не знаю, надо искать по MSE или быть SOтрудником, чтобы ответить. Пока выглядит как просто некая поясняющая шапочка.

Comment: Не только тут, если покликать по фильтрам, то там все сообщения не переведены. Причём, в английском варианте там ещё и ошибка https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323072/260198

Comment: @älёxölüt добавили https://ru.traducir.win/string/11283

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сообщение из двух частей состоит:

1. https://ru.traducir.win/string/11283. Предложил перевод:

   > Тревоги - это способ привлечь внимание сообщества к неприемлемому
   >   контенту или поведению. Подробную информацию вы можете найти в разделе
   >   справки «Что такое тревоги?»
2. https://ru.traducir.win/string/11284. Предложил перевод:

   > Список содержит поставленные вами тревоги и их текущий статус.
   >   Вы можете отфильтровать этот список, используя ссылки в боковой
   >   панели.

**P.S.** там вообще по каждому пункту фильтра текст разный и не переведённый. Будем тред под каждое сообщение создавать?

Comment: Моожет просто моё сообщение отредактировать и добавить туда. Чем кучу тем плодить.

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev вообще, по-хорошему, по каждому сообщению нужно тред с голосованием запилить. Но, судя по прошлым обсуждениям, у нас тут всего полтора рудокопа на мете сидит, которые заморачиваются переводами.

Comment: Там если покликать по списку справа ещё полно строк для перевода :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ угу. Вперёд)